# Find First File in a Branching Directory

Tags: c#, linq, directory, getfiles

I'm trying to find the first .dcm in a directory tree then get the first full path (`a/a/a/123.dcm`) . However ignoring directories where the ie .dcm is not found.

example:

```
a/a/a/123.dcm
a/a/a/1234.dcm
a/a/a/12345.dcm

a/a/b/23.dcm
a/a/b/234.dcm
a/a/b/2345.dcm

a/a/c/23.dcm
a/a/c/234.dcm
a/a/c/2345.dcm
```

Answer should be: `a/a/a/123.dcm`, `a/a/b/23.dcm` and `a/a/c/23.dcm`

I tried:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(inputDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".dcm")).ToArray();
var dir = Directory.GetDirectories(inputDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();

var biggest = files.First();

foreach (var item in dir)
{
   DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(item);
   var q = from i in di.GetFiles("*.dcm", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
           select i.Name;
   var qq = q.First();

   foreach (var items in qq)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(items);
   }
}
```

However what I get is the answer for five directories. Answer:

```
a/a/a/123.dcm
a/a/a/123.dcm
a/a/a/123.dcm
a/a/b/23.dcm 
a/a/c/23.dcm
```

I’m just wondering if there’s a simpler way to do this using LINQ or something else? Thank you so much for your help. Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean the "first" after sorting has been applied? If so what's the sort criteria?

Comment: criteria is it ends with ie: .dcm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a LINQ version:

```
        var inputDir = @"c:\\temp";

        var files = Directory
            .EnumerateFiles(inputDir, "*.dcm", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
            .GroupBy(f => f.Directory.FullName, d => d, (d, f) => new { Directory = d, FirstFile = f.ToList().First() })
            .ToList();

        files.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", f.Directory, f.FirstFile));
```

Comment: forgot to say i'm on 3.5 no directory.enumeratefiles

Comment: For 3.5 just change `EnumerateFiles` to `GetFiles`

Comment: CHeers for the answer...What if I only want first file and not the directory also?

Comment: if you don't need the directory, just change the group by projection to `new { FirstFile = f.ToList().First() }`